# Nonconvex set converging to a convex set despite holes

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, optimization

I'm looking at the example in Figure 4-7 of "Variational Analysis" (Rockafellar and Wets). Basically, there's a sequence of sets $C_{\nu}$ riddled with holes, and it states that the sequence eventually converges to the set $C$ (with the same shape but without holes) as long as the holes get finer and finer and thus vanish in the limit.

If the holes vanish only in the limit, those $x$ in the center of the holes do not appear in $C_{\nu}$ infinitely many times, not even all but finitely many times. Indeed, they appear just once, i.e., for $\nu=+\infty$). Can anyone explain me why then $C_{\nu}$ is said to converge to $C$?

Comment: I don't have access to the figure, but the general answer depends on the open/closed-ness of the holes.  For example the sets $[0,1-\frac{1}{n})\cup(1+\frac{1}{n},2]$ do not converge to the interval $[0,2]$.  But the sets $[0,1-\frac{1}{n})\cup[1+\frac{1}{n},2]$ *do* converge to the interval (I think).

Comment: Consider the case with $C_{\nu}=C - H_{\nu}$, where $H_{\nu}$ is the single (shrinking) hole.  If the $\limsup$ of $H_{\nu}$ is empty, then $C_{\nu}\rightarrow C$.  This can happen if, say, the hole is moving slightly as it shrinks.  You are correct that if the center of the hole is fixed, then that center point (which will be in the intersection of the $H_{\nu}$) will *not* be in the limit of the $C_{\nu}$.

Comment: @JeffSnider page 120 http://www.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/VarAnalysis-RockWets.pdf but it doesn't say anything about open/closed-ness of the holes.

Comment: @mjqxxxx It makes sense, but it doesn't say anything about moving holes either (if you don't have access to the example, you can find the link to the book in the previous comment).

Comment: I think my notion of open/closedness is misleading.  It appears that a convergent sequence of open sets picks up its limit points in the limit.  E.g., $C_\nu=[0,1-1/\nu)$ converges to $[0,1]$.

Comment: Can I have a reference to this last statement?

Comment: It's from def 4.1: Since $N\in\mathbb{N}$ we can write (for the set I have proposed above and in my answer below) $\liminf_{\nu\to\infty} C_\nu := \{ x : \exists x_\nu \in C_\nu \text{ with } x_\nu \to x \}$.  You can come up with quite a few sequences $\{x_\nu\}$ converging to 1 above, or $c$ below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be an arbitrary set with nonempty interior, and a point $c$ in its interior.  Let a hole around $c$ be defined by $$H_\nu := \left\{ x \in C : \Vert c-x \Vert < \frac{1}{\nu} \right\}.$$
Now $$C_\nu := C\setminus H_\nu.$$
It should be obvious (from definition 4.1 in [Rock&Wets](http://www.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/VarAnalysis-RockWets.pdf), p.109) that $$\limsup_\nu C_\nu=\liminf_\nu C_\nu=\lim_\nu C_\nu.$$
For every open set $V$ about $c$ there is some $\nu_0$ such that $\nu\ge\nu_0$ implies $V\cap C_\nu\ne\emptyset$.
Hence, in the limit we have 
$$\lim_{\nu\to\infty} C_\nu = C.$$
This shows how a sequence of sets with a hole containing a stationary point converges to a set not containing that point.

A reference I found helpful in grasping $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of sets is [Hocking & Young](http://books.google.com/books?id=xEVMqtn5jOYC&lpg=PA101&ots=j6RnrK363t&dq=is%20lim%20sup%20of%20open%20sets%20open?&pg=PA101#v=onepage&q=is%20lim%20sup%20of%20open%20sets%20open?&f=false), pp.100-101.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, but now I find myself a bit confused with the general concept of limsup and liminf. If a convergent sequence of open sets picks up its limit points \textit{only} in the limit (that is, the limit point happens only once), isn't that in contrast with liminf being the set of points of $C_{\nu}$ that happen "all but finitely many times" and limsup being the set of points of $C_{\nu}$ that happen "infinitely many times"?

Comment: I don't think $\liminf$ is ``the set of points of $C_\nu$ that happen "all but finitely many times"''.  Look at def 4.1 again, the second line says $\liminf_{\nu\to\infty} C_\nu := \{ x \mid \forall V \in \mathcal{N}(x), \exists N \in \mathcal{N}_\infty, \forall \nu \in N : C_\nu \cap V \ne \emptyset \}$.  This means any point whose ***neighborhoods*** must intersect all but finitely many $C_\nu$ are in the $\liminf$.

Comment: Def. 4.1 (and hence yours) is of course correct, but I've found the above one very often (see, e.g., http://math.ucsb.edu/~labutin/real_analysis_I.pdf, definition 2 in the first page). I find it more intuitive but, however, I can't connect it with yours. What am I missing?

Comment: Besides, the user V.C. claims that $C_{\nu}=[0,1-1/\nu]$ converges to $[0,1)$. I'm getting really confused. Maybe you want to take a look at this question (and related comments): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700374/set-convergence-and-lim-inf-and-lim-sup?noredirect=1#comment1467116_700374

Comment: It appears the authors of your text are using a different definition of $\liminf$ than the other references.  See Exercise 4.2(b) on page 110: you are to show $$\liminf_{\nu\to\infty} C_\nu = \bigcap_{N\in\mathcal{N}_\infty} \text{cl } \bigcup_{\nu\in N} C_\nu,$$ which is different from other references which leave out the closure.

Comment: It ***is*** the same definition as the Hocking and Young reference, however, which states "both $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are closed."